# Generic methods overriding in Strategy pattern

Tags: java, generics, overriding, strategy-pattern

I had to do something similar to the pasted code, and I had two options. The one with generics in the class definition (which had as result some warnings) and the following one.

I couldn't override the base method with the descendant's implementation due to type erasure.

Do you think that one is a correct and safe approach?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<Animal> animals = Arrays.asList(new Dog(), new Cat(), new Dog());
        Map<Class<? extends Animal>, SoundPrinter> printers = new HashMap<Class<? extends Animal>, SoundPrinter>();
        printers.put(Dog.class, new SoundDogPrinter());
        printers.put(Cat.class, new SoundCatPrinter());

        for (Animal animal:animals){
            SoundPrinter printer = printers.get(animal.getClass());
            System.out.println(printer.print(animal));
        }
    }
}

class Animal {

    public String sound() {
        return "animal sound";
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {

    public String sound() {
        return "dog sound";
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {

    public String sound() {
        return "cat sound";
    }
}

abstract class SoundPrinter {

    public <T extends Animal> String print(T animal) {
        return "basic: " + animal.sound();
    }
}

class SoundDogPrinter extends SoundPrinter {

    public String print(Dog dog) {
        return "dog's processed sound: " + dog.sound();
    }
}

class SoundCatPrinter extends SoundPrinter {

    public String print(Cat dog) {
        return "cat's processed sound: " + dog.sound();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are hardcoding the classes in your `Map<Class<? extends Animal>, SoundPrinter>` I don't see what generics adds...

Comment: I don't see a strategy pattern here. What do you want to achieve? A printer per animal? A generic printer?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the SoundPrinter should be an abstract base class for printing all kinds of animals, not just dogs

Comment: @Chirs Yeah yeah, wrote too fast.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I need generics for the print of the base class SoundPrinter.

Comment: @mike I could be wrong, but  I think it's the approach of a base class (SoundPrinter) and the descendants applying a strategy -print- to the passed instances. At least, this looks similar to my point of view: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern.
My point doesn't necessarily have to do with the term. My main point is that I have a couple of strategies extending a base class, and I have a list of objects where different strategies can be applied to different objects.
So I need to pick the right strategy for each object and apply it.
main method is descriptive enough  I think..

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it, the `print` methods in `SoundDogPrinter` and `SoundCatPrinter` do not override `print` in `SoundPrinter`.

The class itself needs to be generic, not the method in the class.  This way, the `print` method will actually be overridden in the `SoundDogPrinter` and `SoundCatPrinter` classes.

```
abstract class SoundPrinter<T extends Animal> {

    public String print(T animal) {
        return "basic: " + animal.sound();
    }
}

class SoundDogPrinter extends SoundPrinter<Dog> {

    public String print(Dog dog) {
        return "dog's processed sound: " + dog.sound();
    }
}

class SoundCatPrinter extends SoundPrinter<Cat> {

    public String print(Cat dog) {
        return "cat's processed sound: " + dog.sound();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also require a `public abstract Class<T> myClass()` method to return the class that the thing is mapped to. This would make the mapping processed endogenous to the classes...

Comment: @rgettman this way I'll have the warning as I mentioned in the description: Unchecked call to 'print(T)' as a member of raw type 'SoundPrinter'.

Comment: @BoristheSpider indeed, it makes things little bit more clear but it doesn't affect the main issue, which is the dilemma warning / the "trick" shown above.
By this change it changes just the adding to the map:
printers.put(catPrinter.prints(), catPrinter);

Comment: I'm not sure how to eliminate that warning (yet).